# Django sorl-thumbnail display image from url

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I have working solr-thumbnail in several parts of my project, but this time I want to display an image from a URL, I have it like this:

```
    {% load thumbnail %}
    {% thumbnail profile_picture_url "150x150" crop="center" as img %}
    <img src="{{ img }}">
    {% endthumbnail %}
```

The view passes the value profile_picture_url as "http://....image.jpg". The image is correctly displayed if I just use:

```
<img src="{{ profile_picture_url }}">
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for sorl-thumbnail?  I thought that it only accepted reference to an ImageField object or something similar.

Comment: Actually I just checked the docs and there is and example using external images, but I could not make it work either. http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SORL-Thumbnail is looking for the image object, not the URL. Pass it `profile_picture` instead of `profile_picture_url` and then call the `url` attribute of `img` in the `src` attribute of the `img` tag.

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail profile_picture "150x150" crop="center" as img %}
  <img src="{{ img.url }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Comment: profile_picture_url is a string, it is not a Field or object, profile_picture_url is just the url of an image on the web.